# PHP: check row exist using mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

i have this two function for create user.first function for insert/create user and other function for check if user was/exist in `MySql` database. but when i send data i see blank page for die(); (if user exsit or user not exist) how to fix this error? and how to print error list in red box i.e:

```
- this user not activate 

- email is empty 

- ....
```

my class:

```
public function createUser($email, $password, $salt, $verification) {

if($this->checkUserFound($email) != true ){die();}

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbUsers (email, password, user_salt, is_verified, is_active, is_admin, verification_code) "
    . "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($query);

    $ver = 0;
    $act = 1;
    $adm = 0;

    $stmt->bind_param("sssiiis", $email, $password, $salt, $ver, $act, $adm, $verification);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function checkUserFound($email) {
    $query = "SELECT email FROM tbUsers where email = ?";

    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        $stmt->bind_result($email);

        //fetch first row of results
        $stmt->fetch();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Check for `mysqli_num_rows`: 0 if not exists, 1 if exists.

Comment: @enapupe: in checkUserFound function? or in `if($this->checkUserFound($email) != true ){die();}` ?!

Comment: Inside checkUserFound, it should return true (or user ID) only when the SQL has one result row.. I don't know the class you are using, but you must have some funcion like $stmt->num_rows().. Anyway, why are you always return false on your function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always going to return `FALSE` (assuming the query successfully executes):

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {

    $stmt->bind_result($email);

    //fetch first row of results
    $stmt->fetch();
    return false;
}
```

You want to change it to:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {

    $stmt->store_result();


    return 0 == $stmt->num_rows ? FALSE : TRUE;

}
```

Then, if the user is found, it will return `TRUE`; if not if will return `FALSE`.

Also, I think it make more sense (semantically) to have this:

```
if($this->checkUserFound($email)){die();}
```

... because you want it to return `TRUE` if the user is found (and end the script because you don't want to insert a duplicate)./

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {

        $stmt->bind_result($email);

        //fetch first row of results
        $stmt->fetch();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```